# PHP Date Input textbox

Tags: javascript

I need to have an date picker in my PHP form , where user can select date from calendar and it s value vl be on textbox.

How to do it in PHP, any tips..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to do it in PHP, any tips..

You need javascript/jQuery for that, have a look at jquery date picker:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/